# Using find command to list top 5 image files by size

Tags: bash, find, sorting

All,
I want to list the top 5 image files (png,jpg) in a given folder.What's the best approach? 
I'm using the following currently but it doesn't give the right output:

```
find . \( -iname \*.png -o -iname \*.jpg \)  -exec ls -lrhS {} \; | sort -n | head -5 | awk '{print $9, "=>",$5}'
```

When I don't pipe to **head** command, I see that the output isn't sorted correctly. 
How can I achieve this

Comment: Since you run ls individually per file, its sorting function won't work. It will "sort" every file individually, so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all pointing me in the right direction. I think I got it to work using:

```
find . \( -iname \*.png -o -iname \*.jpg \) -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l | sort -k5 -r | head -5
```

I will process this output to get the output in desired format(i.e. with suffixes like B, K)

Answer (score 1):

If by "top 5" you mean by size, then you need to tell `sort` which column to sort by; the default will go through all the columns in order, meaning it's going to sort initially by the number of links.  Additionally, without some kind of extension the "human readable" size is not going to sort at all sanely except in GNU `sort`; portable `sort -n` does not know about suffixes like `B`, `K`, etc.  Note also that you lose the sort information you asked `ls` for because it's being run on individual files under control of `find`.  And then your `sort` sorts from lowest to highest, so even fixing that you get the five *smallest* images from `head`.  (And is the `||` before `awk` a typo?  You're saying to run `awk` only if the `find` pipeline fails.)

Combining all of this and optimizing by using `xargs` to batch things up and combining the `head` into the `awk`, what you want is to make sure you have GNU `sort`, then use

```
find . \( -iname \*.png -o -iname \*.jpg \) -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lh | sort -k5gr,5 | awk 'NR <= 5 {print $9, "=>", $5}'
```

Comment: the || before awk is indeed a typo. Also how do I find if I have the GNU sort? I'm on MAC OSX

Comment: `sort --version` will return useful information for GNU sort or an error for traditional Unix `sort`, or possibly information about some other implementation — but OS X uses the version of GNU sort that the version of FreeBSD it last synced with uses (I believe that's FreeBSD 8.0 for Lion; sort is GNU sort 5.93.)

Comment: geekosaur : The command didnt give me the correct output. What does "sort -k5gr,5" do exactly?

Comment: It means general numeric sort (which in GNU sort is supposed to support things like `1.1K`) reversed, from column 5 to column 5 (that is, just the one column).  (It is 1-based, unlike the usual 0-based computer thing.)  That said, I just tried it here and it looks like while GNU `sort` claims to handle the size suffixes on numeric columns, it actually doesn't; you will have to give up on the `-h` option to `ls`, and maybe change the `awk` script to do it instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . \( -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.jpg" \) -printf "%k\t%p\n" | sort -rn | head -5
```

1. Uses find according to your requirements in the current directory (I assume you mean "current directory AND subdirectories, otherwise add `-maxdepth 1`).
2. Prints size (in 1K blocks), followed by tab, followed by filename.
3. Sorts numerically reversed.
4. Picks out the first five lines.

et voilà!

(Possible caveat is file names containing newlines, but in practice I have never seen these. Requires some simple modification to account for that as well)

Comment: I get an error : find: -printf: unknown option. Looks like I will have to install findutils

Comment: @smokinguns Exactly. Are you on OS X or a BSD variant? You need GNU `find` for that, for example through Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "top" as in largest by size?  The `S` in your `ls` command already sorts by size, but `r` reverses the order, sorting smallest to the top.  Perhaps you want to try `-exec ls -lhS {} \; | head -5` (omit the separate `sort`).

Comment: Sorting the output of `ls` (with `l -S`) is pointless, becaue `ls` executes on only a single file at a time; courtesy of `{} \;`

Comment: @Peter.O -- You're absolutely right, I missed that.  I suppose one could omit the find completely using something like `ls -lhS *.png *.PNG *.jpg *.JPG | head -5 | awk '{print $9, "=>",$5}'`.  Depends on what suits his needs.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of very straightforward:

```
find . -ls | sort -nk7 | tail -5
```

Comment: This doesn't restrict to image files, and gives a lot of for the task unnecessary information.

Comment: Asker knows how to list files in good format. I just illustrate how to get 10 top records based on numeric field in 7th position. I assume asker's creativity is enough to correct my deliberate omissions.